# AutoCAD convert polyline to polygon

Tags: polygon, autocad, polyline-creation

How can I convert polyline to polygon when the command MAPPOLYLINETOPOLYGON doesn't work at all?

[image]

I have the map, which is based on the raster PDF. The most reasonable option is redrawing these shapes and make them as polygons for further georeferencing and export as the .kml files.

Unfortunately, I am stuck with converting the closed polyline as a polygon.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-6129F222-C2C8-4340-AF13-51803B178EAB-htm.html

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-C782FDA0-F05F-42EA-B93D-338B2BF062F8-htm.html#GUID-C782FDA0-F05F-42EA-B93D-338B2BF062F8

The MAPPOLYLINETOPOLYGON option is simply not working, because it's unknown in AutoCAD 2020.
I found one of the reason here:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/mappolylinetopolygon-not-working-in-autocad-2020/td-p/9105292

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/AutoCAD-Error-Unknown-command-when-entering-commands.html

but there is no solution for 2D option, which I am dealing with.

I marked my polyline as close, but it didn't help.
https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/topic/41524-how-to-convert-polylines-to-polygons/

Does anyone have any suggestions?